# restrict OpenCL access to Intel CPU?

Tags: cuda, opencl, intel, restrict, slurm

It is currently possible to restrict OpenCL access to an NVIDIA GPU on Linux using the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES env variable. Is anyone aware of a similar way to restrict OpenCL access to Intel CPU devices? (Motivation: I'm trying to force users of a compute server to run their OpenCL programs through SLURM exclusively.)

Comment: there might be an Intel OpenCL driver component that could be removed from your compile/login node that would cause OpenCL codes to fail when launched interactively on compile/login node.

Comment: Seems like an idea worth pursuing - I imagine that one could hide the ICD loader library from binaries that have been dynamically linked to it on the compile node.

Comment: By Intel CPU you mean a Xeon Phi or a Xeon?

Comment: Yes - the host has several Xeon CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to link directly to the Intel OpenCL library (`libintelocl.so` on my system) instead of going through the OpenCL ICD loader.

Comment: my read is that OP doesn't want the user's program to be able to access the Intel CPU that is in the login/compile node interactively, but only from within the job environment (on a compute node).

Comment: Yes - that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In pure OpenCL, the way to avoid assigning tasks to the CPU is to not select it (as platform or device). clGetDeviceIDs can do that using the device_type argument (don't set the CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU bit).

At the ICD level, I guess you could exclude the CPU driver if it's Intel's implementation; for AMD, it gets a little trickier since they have one driver for both platforms (it seems the CPU_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS environment variable can restrict it to one core, but not disable it).

If the goal is to restrict OpenCL programs to running through a specific launcher, such as slurm, one way might be to add a group for that launcher and just make the OpenCL ICD vendor files in /etc/OpenCL (and possibly driver device nodes) usable only by that group.

None of this would prevent a user from having their own OpenCL implementation in place to run on CPU, but it could be enough to guide them to not run there by mistake.